# Sublime close tab behaviour

Tags: sublimetext3

Earlier when I close tab with `ctrl+w` it took me to the last tab i was before. Now sublime switches to the next tab. How can I force to switch last focused tab when I close tab

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TabsExtra / https://github.com/facelessuser/TabsExtra/blob/7846962c2ba966a43c95a22644b265b0f4afb53d/tabs_extra.sublime-settings#L7

Comment: @keith Thanks, it helped me!